# Java Script to find tag value with out ID, Tag Name

Tags: javascript

I want the value of 2nd `<td>`

```
<tr>
    <td>devaraj</td>
    <td>Shiva</td>
</tr>
```

Result expected : 'Shiva'

How can I search for 1st `<td>` tag value and take the value of 2nd `<td>` tag value?

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[1]`

Comment: @adeneo what if you have couple forms on the same page with multiple <td>?

Comment: Then you'd have to select the correct **table** first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which:

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

So to target the 2nd `td`:

```
document.querySelector('table td:nth-child(2)')
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wthwL4jm/) 
or the following snippet

```js
alert(document.querySelector('table td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML)
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>devaraj</td>
        <td>Shiva</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<td>` a name and then get the text value of it 
Something like this:

```
<tr>
<td>devaraj</td>
<td id="nameTD">Shiva</td>
</tr>
```

Script to get the text

```
document.getElementById ( "nameTD" ).innerText
```

result : **Shiva**

---

### Edit1:

If you dont have the ID of the  you can use `$( "td:nth-child(x)")` where is the position you are looking for (Assuming you have only one table in your page);

- for the second, x=2
- for the third , x=3
- ...

So the final code should be:

**Html:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>devaraj</td>
    <td>Shiva</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

**JQuery**
$( "td:nth-child(2)").text()

Check this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/dnzqavdp/) out

Comment: Hi Alundra, in this case i dont have the id name for tag <td>